# How to create an email body from PHP output

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an admission application for a project in school.

Currently the user fills out the form and is then taken to a confirmation page to confirm all their entries are correct. I need help for when they hit submit on the confirmation page it will then send an email that looks like the bootstrap table in confirm.php with all the information entered from the form. I would like to create an email body from the PHP output by reusing the bootstrap table I've already created in confirm.php. If you'd like to see the live form it's located at http://sso.ncat.edu.

confirm.php

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST["NameFirst"]." ".$_POST["NameMiddle"];?>

//then I build the bootstrap table like this

<tr class="warning">
<td>Name</td>
<td><?php echo $Name;?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ought to get you started.

Comment: You'll want to look at [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/book.outcontrol.php). The basic idea would be to wrap the output of your `confirm.php` script in output buffering control, capture the output and use that in your mail body.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you should edit your question to re-focus it on the thing you want to achieve, namely to turn a PHP output (which is in HTML format) into an email. The new title of this question could be something like "How to create an email body from PHP output". I'd also remove the parts that are irrelevant for the problem you want to solve, such as the index.html page part.

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

Dont hold me to this because im still learning php myself. However i have just completed step 2 of my project witch involves what your talking about or at least i think it does. The way i managed to do this was to set all my variables in the confirmation page to look like the following.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone= $_POST['telephone'];

// And so one for all the variables in your form
?>
```

Once all your variables are set it makes it easier to use the echo function for example you can `<?php echo $name ?>`  rather than having to type out `<?php echo $_POST['name'] ?>` and so on again. Once you tidy them up like i did, You can create an email template from your confirmation page that will echo the variables into each field and when the email gets sent all the information should be correctly displayed. I have done this myself and most might say its not the best way to do things and this is why my answer is just a suggestion because im still in the very early days of learning.

If you need help with getting your confirmation page to become a template for your email then i would be happy to help further. I don't want to clog up the answer to much just in case im on the wrong wave length as i can not comment until i get to 50 rep.

Comment: **"If you need help with getting your confirmation page to become a template"**. This is exactly what i'm needing help with!

Comment: Mark i have been to the link provided above in your OP, is it possible for me to visit the confirmation page without filling the form in? i have had a look at the source code and your review.php file wont allow direct access. Is there a way round this so i can see exactly what your confirmation page is like and how you want things to look.